# CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, cocoapods

My app was working fine until I did 2 small changes.

1. On Target runner in Xcode I enabled bitcode for the project.
2. I update the Android studio to the latest version.

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.0.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (211.7798), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), io.flutter (63.2.2)

After that When I run my flutter app on iOS simulator I'm getting this error.
Although I have disabled bitcode and tried again.I got same error. I installed and reinstalled cocapoads still same error. I don't know what causing this error. Can you help? please

```
 Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
 CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that          responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
 Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
 For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
 To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-  started.html#installation for instructions.

 CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
 Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: hmm mine i used brew and seems fine

Comment: cd ios && pod repo update && pod update && cd ..

Comment: But you don't need brew to install cocoapods anymore. Referred from flutter official docs.

Comment: My app was running last night. All I did today was that 2 changes. I am getting this error. I don't know how to fix it cos' I'm not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: Cocoapods is installed but Android Studio somehow not detecting it. How can I resolve this?

Comment: When I run flutter doctor from terminal, there is no problem. When I do it with android studio, I get the same error, it happened after updating android studio to Bumblebee version.

Comment: Same here after Android Studio update to bumblebee

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70881845/376967 .. here is a solution that work

Answer (score 28):

> UPD: Fixed in 2021.1.1 patch 1, [see release notes here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/02/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-patch-1.html)

This might happen because AndroidStudio doesn't know anything about `$PATH` provided in `~/.*rc` files (`.bashrc`,`.zshrc`, etc.)

You can ensure by launching it from terminal:

```sh
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

> EDIT: It's a confirmed bug in Bumblebee release

> The workaround is to add missing flag:

```sh
chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv
```

You have to do it only once

Comment: open in terminal works... from dock not :-(

Comment: If you are not sure how to edit the profile to add the path, this is a good short step by step writeup: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: Still can't get this to work I have updated the .zhhrc and .profile with `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin` but still does not work. Tried `Invalidate Cache & Restart` even restarted my mac and still no luck.

Comment: Updated the answer, with a working fix. It is a confirmed bug of Bumblebee release.

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting this error: CocoaPods' output:
↳
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Comment: Very helpful fix before the patch. For those who can't update Android studio with the latest patch just run the above command with a `-x` instead of a `+x` and then try updating. @BufferUnderflow it would be great if you could add this to your answer. Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that running Android Studio from terminal solved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Open terminal run -> `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Try again...And it should work.

Comment: This is the actual answer. The binary seems to have no execute permissions after update. Cheers

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting this error: CocoaPods' output:
↳
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Answer (score 9):

I got an exception on the pod availability check.

```
which pod
```

It seems that $PATH env for the updated studio is not picked properly.  (you can check it by enabling verbose logging mode on the flutter plugin).

Workaround is to start Android studio from the terminal:

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

**Updated:
Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Patch 1 fixes this [issue.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97251#issuecomment-1030192870)**

Answer (score 7):

I came across this problem too using Android studio on Apple Silicon MacBook launching from command line or directly both failed

I updated the ruby version to 2.7.3 using rbenv, and then it worked from the command line.

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Note: default macOS system ruby is version is 2.6.8, and there are some incompatible gems with this version

Comment: doing open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app and updating pod repo solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If the top voted solution doesn't fix this for you with the Bumblebee release, then you can try the beta Chipmunk release of Android Studio.

I am running the M1 Mac and this version 2021.2.1 Beta 1 is able to run the flutter apps from the toolbar correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've searched all of solutions, and current post's answers do the trick. But basically it seems like flutter android studio(only lately-updated bumblebee version) plug-in triggers the pod error, since both xcode and android studio terminal run work just fine.

We might have to keep tracking [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97251). Before flutter team gives a clear answer, i'm planning to use `flutter run --debug`, since terminal run provides "r" for hot reload and "R" for hot restart. Or we can also use `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running:

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i check $PATH variable and in this do not exist path to `pod` executable

Using MacBook Pro M1 with pod installed by brew