# Cocoapods error after updating to Android Studio 2021.1.1

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

I updated yesterday to the new Android Studio 2021.1.1

Now i get the following error, when i run my app on the ios emulator:

> Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
>
> ```
> You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
>
> This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
>
> This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
>
> To re-install:
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods
>
> CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
> ```

I tried everything for many hours.

At the end i go back to Android Studio 2020 previous version and it works perfect.

Any ideas?

Update:
This works for me:

uninstall cocoapods then
reinstalling cocoapods via homebrew.
Afterwards I did an "pod repo update"

Comment: See this answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870802/8094969